# How to get complete Issuer Name from cert.pem in php

Tags: php, x509certificate

I want to get the whole issuer name from `cert.pem` and I have this output:

```
Array, TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1
```

the output should be like this:

```
CN=TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local
```

the code I am using :

```
$data = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents('cert.pem'));
$issuername = $data['issuer'];
echo implode(", ",$issuername);
```

but only I got the first is `CN` but cannot get `DN` values!

Comment: `Array` means you tried to force an array into a string context. Do a `var_dump` of $issuername first, to see what it actually contains.

Comment: @CBroe the result of `var_dump` of `issuername` is `array(2) { ["DC"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "local" [1]=> string(3) "gov" [2]=> string(7) "extgazt" } ["CN"]=> string(19) "TSZEINVOICE-SubCA-1" }`

Comment: Only `CN` contains a string value; `DC` is itself an array, and that's why you get the _word_ `Array` when trying to apply implode directly - you need to implode (or otherwise format) this value first, and modify it inside the array.